# springMVC: view won't submit values to controller

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I've got the following setup:

```
public class MyController extends BaseFormController {
  public MyController() {
    setCommandClass(MyObject.class);
    setCommandName("object");
    setSessionForm("true);
  }

  @Override
  protected ModelAndView onSubmit(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object command, BindException errors)
        throws Exception {
    MyObject o = (MyObject) command;
    ...
  }
```

MyObject has a member of type MyOtherObject which, in turn, has a member `Set<String> foo`:

```
public class MyObject {
  ...
  MyOtherObject otherObject;
  ...
}

public class MyOtherObject {
  ...
  Set<String> foo = new HashSet<String>();
  ...
}
```

and all corresponding setters and getters are implemented. Then I've got a view, written in jsp and:

```
<form:form method="POST" action="" commandName="object" ...
...
    <form:select path="otherObject.foo" multiple="multiple" size="4">
      <c:forEach var="entry" items="${listOfItems}">
        <option value="${entry.size}" <c:if test="${!entry.enabled}">disabled</c:if>>${entry.name}</option>
      </c:forEach>
    </form:select>
 ...
 </form:form>
```

My goal is to map the `size`s of some entries in the list to the set `foo`.

All other entries in the form are set to the values the user types in, so the overall syntax should be right. However when it comes to this multiple select form, which should be mapped to object.otherObject.foo, the controller acts as if no values whatsoever were ever provided in the view, i.e. even if I were to select multiple values from the box before hitting submit, the `command` object in the Controller still gets an empty otherObject.foo member.

Any ideas what may be causing this?

P.S. I also tried adding a `Set<String> foo` directly in MyObject and using it in the `path=""` of the view. It still didn't work out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of poking around I found the solution - foo had to be declared as `String[] foo` and from there on spring took care of all the rest, just as expected. Beats me why spring would use "old-fashioned" arrays in this day and age but it apparently does.

Answer (score 0):

Did you override formBackingObject method? if yes, did you assign MyOtherObject to MyObject?

Comment: I have implemented `formBackingObject()` in my controller, yes. The assignment of the members is also correct, because all other member variables (boolean, int, String, etc.) work without any problems. The only problem child is the `Set<String>` which should get populated in the multi-select box.

Comment: then did you put anything in your HashTable??? Because from the snippet it looks that you are passing an empty foo object to the select.

Comment: the HashTable (`foo`) is supposed to be empty when I first run this view. The problem I'm experiencing is exactly that nothing gets put into it.